# How to do I block IP & computer name from appearing in the SMTP email headers when sending from the Outlook Desktop application?

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, privacy

I am using the Windows Outlook 2016 application, connected to 2 different hosted IMAP/SMTP email accounts (different vendors), and when I send out emails and compare the email headers, one is more "private", and the other spills out my IP address and computer name.  Is this an Outlook or email vendor setting that can block the "loose" email account from sending out my IP and computer name?

Note: I was able to use a VPN to change my "X-Source-IP", but it's a bit annoying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Email messages typically keep a record in their headers of where they have come from. While it's optional for mail servers and clients to add custom headers like `X-Source-IP`, you have no control over it in Outlook.